# Maven repository for mlibwrapper_jar not working

Tags: spring, maven, java, jai, media-library

Could someone share the right maven repository for mlibwrapper_jar ?  I searched it in internet but did not get info.

The below old one is not working:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.medialib</groupId>
    <artifactId>mlibwrapper_jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this repository:
https://maven.gentics.com/maven2/

and your pom.xml dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mlibwrapper</groupId>
  <artifactId>mlibwrapper_jai</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will check it.